# cakephp 3 inserting data in other controller .. but data not getting saved and returned no errors

Tags: insert, cakephp-3.0

Here is my code 
PurchaseDetails from another model 
inserting data in this table called PurchaseDetails

```
$purchaseobjev = TableRegistry::get('PurchaseDetails'); // other model
$PDvari = $purchaseobjev->newEntity();

$PDvari->purchase_origins_id = 11;
$PDvari->product_codes_id = 1;

$PDvari->store_lists_id =1;
$PDvari->hand_types_idsss =1;
$PDvari->core_pattern =1;
$PDvari->color_list =1;
$PDvari->measurement_types_id = 1; 
$PDvari->measurement_inventories_id = 1; 
$PDvari->measurement_value =1;
$PDvari->measurement_total =1;
$PDvari->price_range = 1;

if( $purchaseobjevs->save($PDvari) ) {
    echo "here";die;
}else{
    echo "no";die;
}
```

Comment: please share with us `debug($PDvari)` result

Comment: The first two lines use `$purchaseobjev` but the save uses `$purchaseobjevs`.

Comment: Now i am able to save my data.. but while send inserting the data in loop.. the last set of arrays only inserting that means if am passing 5 rows to insert .. only one row getting inserted..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $PDvari = array_values($PDvari);
    $articles = TableRegistry::get('PurchaseDetails');
    $entities = $articles->newEntities($PDvari);
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $maxId = $articles->save($entity);
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.